# Duplicate div outside the current div

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Problem**

I am trying to clone a div when a user click the *add* button. The problem is that I am cloning right now the div inside the current one. I would like to add it to the .wrapper div but that fails. I tried already a few other things like appendTo('.wrapper'), but without success.

You can see when you click the add button, the indentation is not correct from the fields that are being cloned.

**Example** https://jsfiddle.net/duikboot/1sakxpzq/

Code where I do the clone:

```
var pd = $('.product_data').last().clone();
var id_count = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.add_item', function() {
  var clone = pd.clone().prop('id', 'product_' + id_count);
  $(this).prevAll('.product_data').first().append(clone.hide());
  clone.slideDown('fast');
  id_count++;
});
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: should not you clone labels also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.append()` and the content inside selected container as last child. You need to use `.after()` for adding content as next sibling:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_item', function() {
  var clone = pd.clone().prop('id', 'product_' + id_count);
  $(this).prevAll('.product_data').first().after(clone.hide());
  clone.slideDown('fast');
  id_count++;
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6v7eesh0/)**

Comment: Ok, that makes sense thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just replace `first()` by `parent()` in your click event , because you're referring to 
`.product_data` class and not to the `.wrapper` parent class

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_item', function() {
  var clone = pd.clone().prop('id', 'product_' + id_count);
  $(this).prevAll('.product_data').parent().append(clone.hide());
  clone.slideDown('fast');
  id_count++;
});
```

Comment: This will append new div after clicked button.